# Simple_form & Twitter Bootstrap: Form labels unaligned, missing HTML in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, simple-form

When I go into production, my forms change causing the labels and fields to be unaligned from each other. In development it works correctly but not in production.

Here is what I mean:

```
Development
<div class="control-group string required">
    <div class="control-label">
        <label for="store_business_name" class="string required">
            <abbr title="required">
                *
            </abbr> Business
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" size="50" name="store[business_name]" id="store_business_name" class="string required span3">
        <p class="help-block">
            The Business the store will belong to
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

Production
<div class="control-group string required">
    <label for="store_business_name" class="string required">
        <abbr title="required">
            *
        </abbr> Business
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" size="50" name="store[business_name]" id="store_business_name" class="string required span3">
        <p class="help-block">
            The Business the store will belong to
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you look closely, the `<div class="control-label">` disappears in production. I'm not using any type of bootstrap gem (dependent on gems I can't install). Is this a known issue, how is this fixed?

---

```
<%= simple_form_for(@store, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
    <%= render :partial => "shared/error_message", :locals => { :f => f } %>
    <div class="span12">
        <%= f.input :business_name, :label => 'Business', :input_html => { :class => "span3" }, :hint => "The Business the store will belong to" %>
        <%= f.input :online_store, :label => 'Online Store', :as => :boolean %>
        <%= f.input :address, :input_html => { :class => "span3" }, :placeholder => "451 University Avenue, Palo Alto, CA 94301", :hint => "For offline store" %>
        <%= f.input :website, :input_html => { :class => "span3" }, :placeholder => "www.somewebsite.com", :hint => "For online store" %>
        <%= f.input :phone_number, :input_html => { :class => "span3" }, :placeholder => "(650) 798-2800" %>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <%= f.button :submit, "Done", :class => 'btn btn-primary span2' %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you past the view generating this output please ? Have you sure you code is the same between env ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Simple_form are you using? How did you integrate bootstrap?

Presuming you used simple_form's wiki to integrate with twitter/bootstrap then please verify:

1. lib/simple_form/contained_input_component.rb is being loaded and is implemented as-is
2. config/initializers/simple_form.rb is calling the above library
3. there is only one simple_form.rb in config/initializers and config/production

If all of the above is in order, please update the question with your view code.

Comment: It was an issue with the gem. I was using 2.0.0.rc. I upgraded to 2.0.1 and everything is good now. Thank you for you concern.

Comment: @Railslearner: No worries, on a side note - always check for the last stable release when integrating any new gem and explicitly define gem versions in the Gemfile. Bleeding edges are for home experiments, secret labs and bug testers :P